# notify_url not working in new paypal

Tags: paypal-sandbox, notify

I have registered to paypal on live on https://www.paypal.com. Not verified for live.
I can login to https://developer.paypal.com with above login detail.
Here I go for sandbox accounts, I have created two account, one business and one personal.
(Sandbox account are verified)

I am trying for payment integration with Paypal with html form.
I have specified the notify_url, payment goes all right but no notification in notify_url.

I have double checked the notify_url, its working fine.

Anybody there, what seems to be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using buttons created and saved to a PayPal account? You may not be able to define a `notify_url` value through a hosted button. IPN may also be disabled in the account.

Log into the seller account receiving the payment, enable IPN, and set a URL for the post to be sent to. From the "Instant Payment Notification Preferences" section (where you enable IPN) you can view the IPN History which shows you the last 28 days of IPN posts sent for that account.

Comment: Can you please clarify on this: "You may not be able to define a notify_url value through a hosted button." Do you mean I cannot integrate a button hosted my site with notify_url?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem. A buy now hosted button was saved without errors, but a `notify_url` was not notified by paypal.

There is a work around, you can specify a `notify_url` in your profile globally. 
[paypal docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#setting-up-ipn-notifications-on-paypal)

Comment: When you create a "buy now" hosted button via API NVP specify notify url by key "NOTIFYURL", not "notify_url"

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I just had the same problem. This caused it in my case:

I have been testing on the development server. This server was not accessible for IPs outside of our company (for security purposes). So the IPN-call from paypal never came trough to the IPN-script on the development server.

Took me one day to figure that out...

Comment: How could i know if this is my server issue ? My paypal checkout goes perfect. return url everything else is working fine. but no hit to the notify_url occurs. I also check with IPN simulator and it runs perfect. Also the important this is that i have done so many test purhcases (successfull). But when i go to my merchant account dashboard or reports i see no transactions. This is what i am facing in sandbox account

Comment: I got exact same problem. notify_url worked for me on the sandbox last week. However, it just stopped working today when I tried again. I'm picking my hair out one at a time to figure out why...I will update the answer later when I found the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you already done the test of the IPN via the simulator https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ and checked if it's OK?

Have you checked you set the "pixel" in your HTML form? If it's missing, the `notify_url` won't work. This solution worked for me.

For Sandbox, use : `<img alt="" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">`